# Strange behavior when slicing Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am observing some really strange behavior while attempting to slice data using pandas MultiIndex. The version I am using is Pandas 0.13.1

I have a csv file containing some time series stock index data which I am reading into a DataFrame. I then reset the row index of the DataFrame so that it is indexed by TradingDate and PriceType where PriceType is one of ['open','close','high']
Here is the code below:

```
sharesIndexDataDF=pd.read_csv('./stock_index_data.csv')
sharesIndexDF=sharesIndexDataDF.set_index(['TradingDate','PriceType'])
```

I now attempt the slice:

```
sharesIndexDF.ix[('2014/02/21','open'):('2014/02/24','open')]
```

but I end up with this error

---

*KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 sharesIndexDF.ix[('2014/02/21','open'):('2014/02/24','open')]
...
KeyError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (1)'*

The stranger thing is that when I use a slightly different file where the strings
['open','close','high'] have been replaced by ['categA', 'categB', 'categC'] resp. the code works fine:

```
sharesIndexDataDF=pd.read_csv('./stock_index_data_reps.csv')
sharesIndexDF=sharesIndexDataDF.set_index(['TradingDate','PriceType'])
sharesIndexDF.ix[('2014/02/21','categA'):('2014/02/24','categA')]
```

produces

```
                      Nasdaq    S&P 500          Russell 2000
TradingDate PriceType           
2014/02/21  categA   4282.17     1841.07     1166.25
            categB   4263.41     1836.25     1164.63
            categC   4284.85     1846.13     1168.43
2014/02/24  categA   4273.32     1836.78     1166.74
```

The contents of the files are as follows:

stock_index_data.csv:

```
TradingDate,PriceType,Nasdaq,S&P 500,Russell 2000
2014/02/21,open,4282.17,1841.07,1166.25
2014/02/21,close,4263.41,1836.25,1164.63
2014/02/21,high,4284.85,1846.13,1168.43
2014/02/24,open,4273.32,1836.78,1166.74
2014/02/24,close,4292.97,1847.61,1174.55
2014/02/24,high,4311.13,1858.71,1180.29
2014/02/25,open,4298.48,1847.66,1176
2014/02/25,close,4287.59,1845.12,1173.95
2014/02/25,high,4307.51,1852.91,1179.43
2014/02/26,open,4300.45,1845.79,1176.11
2014/02/26,close,4292.06,1845.16,1181.72
2014/02/26,high,4316.82,1852.65,1188.06
2014/02/27,open,4291.47,1844.9,1179.28
2014/02/27,close,4318.93,1854.29,1187.94
2014/02/27,high,4322.46,1854.53,1187.94
2014/02/28,open,4323.52,1855.12,1189.19
2014/02/28,close,4308.12,1859.45,1183.03
2014/02/28,high,4342.59,1867.92,1193.5
```

stock_index_data_reps.csv:

```
TradingDate,PriceType,Nasdaq,S&P 500,Russell 2000
2014/02/21,categA,4282.17,1841.07,1166.25
2014/02/21,categB,4263.41,1836.25,1164.63
2014/02/21,categC,4284.85,1846.13,1168.43
2014/02/24,categA,4273.32,1836.78,1166.74
2014/02/24,categB,4292.97,1847.61,1174.55
2014/02/24,categC,4311.13,1858.71,1180.29
2014/02/25,categA,4298.48,1847.66,1176
2014/02/25,categB,4287.59,1845.12,1173.95
2014/02/25,categC,4307.51,1852.91,1179.43
2014/02/26,categA,4300.45,1845.79,1176.11
2014/02/26,categB,4292.06,1845.16,1181.72
2014/02/26,categC,4316.82,1852.65,1188.06
2014/02/27,categA,4291.47,1844.9,1179.28
2014/02/27,categB,4318.93,1854.29,1187.94
2014/02/27,categC,4322.46,1854.53,1187.94
2014/02/28,categA,4323.52,1855.12,1189.19
2014/02/28,categB,4308.12,1859.45,1183.03
2014/02/28,categC,4342.59,1867.92,1193.5
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you would do well to read here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex, your index needs to be sorted